# null values being inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest, api

I have a REST API that should save the contents of a JSON into a MySQL database. However it's inserting everything as null? That is weird, because whenever the JSON is sent from the swift SDK it works just fine.

```
 public function saveTracking($request, $response, $args) {
        if(!$this->validToken($response)) {
            return $response;
        }
        $data = $request->getParsedBody();
        $tracking_data = json_decode(json_encode($data['tracking']), FALSE);
        $total_records = 0;
          //error_log(print_r($tracking_data, true));

        foreach($tracking_data as $key => $value) {
            $tracking = new EstablishmentTracking();
            $tracking->mobile_user_id = $this->authUser->id;
            $tracking->report_date = $value->report_date;
            $tracking->establishment_id = $value->establishment_id;
            if ($value->platform == MobileUser::ANDROID || $value->platform == MobileUser::IOS) {
                $tracking->platform = $value->platform;
            }
            $tracking->purchase_id = $value->purchase_id;

            error_log(print_r($tracking, true));
            $this->establishmentService->saveEstablishmentTracking($tracking);
            $total_records++;
        }
        $arr = array("status" => "ok"
                    ,"total_records" => $total_records
                    );
        print_r($arr);
        $newResponse = $response->withJson($arr);
        return $newResponse;
    }
```

After adding a line that prints the contents of the variable, I got the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [establishment_id] => 39
    [report_date] => 2018-05-31 18:45:05
    [platform] => android
    [purchase_id] => 0
```

Is it not sending the JSON correctly as an array? What seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the json object causing problem is  $tracking_data  , the json decode you are using needs to have second value from false to true, this will convert it into php array which is iterable with keys stdClass may not reveal its properties